# Why does sympy.solve return results with piecewise and a constant condition?

Tags: python, sympy

by running the code below:

```
from sympy import *

a = symbols('a')
x = symbols('x')
f = Piecewise((a, x > a), (a+x, True))
results = solve(f.subs(a, 3) - x**3, x)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

i got following results:

```
1/(3*(sqrt(717)/18 + 3/2)**(1/3)) + (sqrt(717)/18 + 3/2)**(1/3)
Piecewise(((-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(717)/18 + 3/2)**(1/3) + 1/(3*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(717)/18 + 3/2)**(1/3)), (8*18**(1/3) + 12**(1/3)*(1 + sqrt(3)*I)**2*(sqrt(717) + 27)**(2/3))/(12*(1 + sqrt(3)*I)*(sqrt(717) + 27)**(1/3)) >= -3), (nan, True))
Piecewise((1/(3*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(717)/18 + 3/2)**(1/3)) + (-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(sqrt(717)/18 + 3/2)**(1/3), (8*18**(1/3) + 12**(1/3)*(1 - sqrt(3)*I)**2*(sqrt(717) + 27)**(2/3))/(12*(1 - sqrt(3)*I)*(sqrt(717) + 27)**(1/3)) >= -3), (nan, True))
```

i'm wondering what does the 2 Piecewise results mean. Conditions here are constants with I involved, which does not make any sense to me.

Comment: It looks like the comparison and imaginary numbers confuse sympy here. Note that `x = symbols('x', real=True); solve(3 + x - x ** 3, x)` also returns one real and two imaginary solutions.